# Issue mapping custom domain to Azure Web App

Tags: azure, dns, azure-web-app-service

I own a domain name and am trying to map it to an Azure Web App that I successfully created.

I created an A record, C record, and Txt (as required by Azure) on Godaddy and configured Custom Domains in Azure (as pictured below).  The message I'm getting back now is:

> The resource you are looking for has been removed, had its name
>   changed, or is temporarily unavailable.

Any suggestions?

[image]

[image]

Comment: The site works if you access it using dnnappserver.azurewebsites.net.  Looks like you're using DNN.  There must be a DNN configuration setting for the domain name.  Have you done that?

Comment: OMG!  I can't believe I forgot that.  Let me try it right now.

Comment: Thanks very much. CSharpRocks!!  I'm new to Azure.  I would have wasted the day!

Comment: As I don't you exactly what DNN setting to change, can you answer your own question and mark it as the answer?

Answer (score 0):

By looking in **https://www.digwebinterface.com/**

https://www.digwebinterface.com/?hostnames=dnnappserver.scm.azurewebsites.net%0D%0Asmarttapp.com%0D%0Awww.smarttapp.com&type=&ns=resolver&useresolver=8.8.4.4&nameservers=

[image]

Everything seems perfect and even mapping is correct. Even site are working by custom domain :)